# Select all rows after sum of field reach specific number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like below

```
ID | Name | Value
---+------+-------
1  | X    |  10
2  | y    |  15
3  | z    |  3
4  | A    |  20
5  | B    |  6
```

I want to select all rows that comes after `sum(Value)` reach specific number 
Examples :-

If that specific number is 11, the result set will be:

```
2 | y |  15
3 | z |  3
4 | A |  20
5 | B |  6
```

If that specific number is 25, the result set will be

```
3 | z |  3
4 | A |  20
5 | B |  6
```

If that specific number is 30, the result set will be

```
4 | A |  20
5 | B |  6
```

If that specific number is 50, the result set will be

```
5 | B |  6
```

Comment: IF number is 30 then only 6 and IF number is 50 then nothing OR null ??

Comment: if number is 30 , then   A and B because A violate the total number 30 , the total with A will be (48)  , without A will be (28)
same for 50 , it should return B because B violate the total number 50 , the total With B will be (54) , without B will be (48)
I hope you get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this correlated subquery approach to calculate running totals:

```
declare @value int
set @value = 11

;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT t.*, 
      SumBefore = (SELECT SUM(Value)
                   FROM dbo.TableName t2
                   WHERE t2.ID <= t.ID)
   FROM TableName t
)
SELECT CTE.*
FROM CTE
WHERE SumBefore > @value
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/02992/12/0)</kbd>

Comment: Excellent , Worked as expected , thank you so much Tim , 
if u have any recommended articles for CTE ,  i will appreciate to share them with me , it is first time to read  CTE , Thanks again Tim .

Comment: @Bassem: CTE is nothing special, you can use it for recursive queries(f.e. if you have a column in  a table that is a foreign-key to the same table). But apart form that it's just like a named subquery or view. So you could also use a subquery. I prefer a CTE because it's more readable and maintainable.

Comment: @Bassem: btw, a CTE is a [common-table-expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972(v=SQL.120).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple query (If you have SQL Server 2008+):

```
SELECT ID, Name, Value
FROM (
    SELECT *
        , SUM(Value) OVER (ORDER BY ID) As SumNow
    FROM yourTable) t
WHERE 
    (SumNow > ?);
```

**[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b143/3)**

---

For older version of SQL Servers you can use this query:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Value
FROM yourTable t
WHERE 
    ((SELECT SUM(Value) 
      FROM yourTable ti 
      WHERE ti.ID <= t.ID) > ?);
```

**[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b143/7)**

Comment: Thanks shA.t , 
did u test it in ur machine ? Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Comment: The second example works , Thanks shA.t , the first one keep saying  Incorrect syntax .